# Unable to Create a Sub-Total in the POWERPIVOT

Tags: calculated-columns, powerpivot, calculated-field, subtotal

I am pretty new with POWERPIVOT tables. I have searched for a bit of time now to resolve my problem but I have been unsuccessful so far. As you can see below, I have created a POWERPIVOT table in Excel 2013 that is composed of two FACT tables, which are based on: 1) a sheet where the clients can insert vote 1 budget entries; and, 2) another sheet where the clients can insert vote 5 budget entries. Also, a few DIMENSION tables have been added to the combination in order to link the Branch names and the expenditure type. Please note that this is only a simple example of what I am trying to produce.

[image]

However, **my main problem** is that I can't add a sub-total that would sum Salary, Operating and Revenues for Vote 1 and Vote 5 separately. What I would like to show is the following:

[image]

Please note that I have tried calculated columns and calculated fields at the best of my knowledge but the results are always showing another set of columns for Salary, Operating and Revenues but what I need is just one column that sum the three components so it displays Salary, Operating, Revenues and Sub-Total. Does anyone know how to resolve this problem that I am facing since a long time?

Thanks to gurus.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you start by putting both budgets in the one table and an extra column to designate Vote id., Otherwise I fearyou will need to add a calculated column concatenating the Branch and Expenditure Type in each table, then doing a LOOKUPVALUE from Vote1 on the concatenated column to Vote5 and pull back the value.

Comment: Actually, you can forget the concatenate, LOOKUPVALUE can search on multiple columns.